# if a website is not angular then how protract is used?

Tags: angular, protractor

I am not able to set wait until an element is present as the website is not angular and when I set

`browser.wait` like expected conditions, it says that no angular is present. So if I want to set the following then how to do ??

if possible then also make me understand the working or protractor finding elements and all other actions for non-angular website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To deal with non angular elements we use below statement in code

```
 browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
```

Comment: so when I write that line, will it not wait for any angular elements present in the website ??  how to use code for angular elements then ???

Comment: browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true); this will work for angular elements

Comment: can we use both lines in a single file.. like some websites may be partial angular then ??

Comment: @Shyam3 - Yes you can use it.

Answer (score 1):

browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;